# 'Don't lose file' in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, directory

In TextEdit, when you move an opened file to another folder, TextEdit find out the actual folder of the file and ask you if he can save it in the new folder. If I had opened a file in Objective-C and moved it to a different folder, how can I find out in which folder the file is now?

Comment: You don't have an opened file in Objective-C. Objective-C is the language. I will assume you mean an opened file in XCode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ["Kernel Queues"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH5-SW2)
to monitor an open file descriptor for changes such as rename operations
(and from a system call trace this seems to be what TextEdit does).

Here is some simple sample code: http://doc.geoffgarside.co.uk/kqueue/file.html.
I haven't used it, but may be it helps.

You can determine the path of an open file with a `fcntl()` system call
on the file descriptor. Example (and this is tested :-):

```
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:...];

char pathbuf[MAXPATHLEN];
if (fcntl([fh fileDescriptor], F_GETPATH, pathbuf) == -1) {
    NSLog(@"could not get file path: %s", strerror(errno));
} else {
    NSString *path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                          stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:pathbuf
                                                      length:strlen(pathbuf)];
}
```

This gives the current path, even if the file has been moved to a different
location after is was opened.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I will try it and then I will tell here if it works.

Comment: It's not working. 'path' is equal to '/dev/ttys000/' instead of the real folder. It is right when fh is defined while loading, but when the user need to save, and a new 'path' is created, it became '/dev/ttys000/'.

Comment: Correction: It is '/dev/ttys000/' all the time, in any case.

Comment: @GammaStudio: That probably means that `fh = nil`. Because then `[fh fileDescriptor] = 0`, which is the fd for stdin, so that `fcntl(...)` returns the path of the current tty.

Comment: But fh is not null, fh is equal to `[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:file]`, where `file` is a NSString with the file/folder location. How can I repair this? Something need to change if it is a folder instead of a file?

Comment: @GammaStudio: I did not test it (yet) with folders. But what is the value of `[fh fileDescriptor]` ?

Comment: The value of `[fh fileDescriptor]` is Null. But I can't understand. My `fh` was declared in that way:
`NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:file];`
`file` is an NSString with the file location, and it's is a valid path, since it is working in different functions like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, the output in the NSLog should be an int. The value of `[fh fileDescriptor]` is 0.

Comment: It took me a long time,but the fact is that NSFileHandle only works with files, not folders, so I added a .temp file inside the folder so I could track its position, and it worked like a charm. Thanks :)